# Prisma SQL Server connection error in .env file

Tags: sql-server, prisma, next.js13

I am new in using prisma and I need to connect to my existing database in SQL Server.

`schema.prisma`

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url = "sqlserver://10.86.240.10;initial catalog=testdb;user=sa;password=Pa$$w0rd;trustServerCertificate=true;"
  //url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

`.env`

```
DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://10.86.240.10;initial catalog=testdb;user=sa;password=Pa{%24}{%24}w0rd;trustServerCertificate=true;"
```

As you can see in my schema, if I put my connection string in `schema.prisma` everything works fine. I can query in my database but for security purposes, I need to put my connection string in `.env` file and after that it starts to give an error of `Authentication failed for user sa`.

I tried to escape my password since it has a special character, I tried these: `{Pa$$word}`, `{Pa%24%24w0rd}` and `Pa{%24}{%24}w0rd` but nothing works. I also tried to remove the double quote in my connection string in `.env` but it doesn't work too.

Did I miss something? Please help.

Comment: Aside... on the topic of security purposes, it's bad practice to use `sa` credentials from applications. Create and permission dedicated accounts for use by applications following the Principle of Least Privilege.

Comment: Have you tried using your `.env` with single quotes around variable values instead of double quotes, curly braces and percent encodings?

Comment: sir @AlwaysLearning yes i tried it but it always says Authentication failed

Comment: `DATABASE_URL='sqlserver://10.86.240.10;initial catalog=testdb;user=sa;password=Pa$$w0rd;trustServerCertificate=true;'`

Comment: when I did `npx prisma db pull`, I use this connection string in my `.env` file and it's working fine `'sqlserver://10.86.240.10;database=testdb;user=sa;password=Pa$$w0rd;trustServerCertificate=true;'`. I am confuse why it fails when I do query

Comment: Perhaps because `initial catalog=testdb;` is not the same thing as `database=testdb;`? `Initial Catalog` is listed as a connection string keyword for [OLE DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server) but not for the [`mssql` module on NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#configuration-1).

Comment: I also tried the `database` sir but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got it now, the answer is here [Escaping values in connection url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver16#escaping-values-in-the-connection-url).

It turns out that I'm doing it wrong, the proper way to escape the special character in `.env` file is like this:`password=Pa{$}{$}w0rd` or `password=Pa{$$}w0rd`.

You have to wrap every special characters with curly braces to make it work.